# Can I stop Microsoft Accessibility Insights for Windows from reaching out for updates

Tags: accessibility-insights

Currently Microsoft Accessibility Insights reaches out consistently to check for updates. Although this is great is causes issues with our release process internally as it effectively stops the software from working update the update has been applied.

Is there any way of restricting this check to a manual check or a deferrable update.

We would really like to manage the updates more effectively.

Comment: You can use a tool like Fiddler to monitor what URL the application is calling out to, and then add that URL to your hosts file to block all traffic to it. That will effectively block any updates from occurring, but you'll need to remove it when you _do_ want to update or just download the latest version from their website fresh each time.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Disclaimer: I work for the Accessibility Insights team.</sup>

*NB: There is an issue filed for this in the Accessibility Insights for Windows repo at https://github.com/microsoft/accessibility-insights-windows/issues/1644.*

Your question is very similar to [this issue requesting manual control over updates](https://github.com/microsoft/accessibility-insights-windows/issues/1186), which we opted not to implement. Part of our security requirements is that we *must* be able to force an update for security reasons. We follow an evergreen model and support just the two most recent Production releases at any point in time.

The two most recent releases were atypical in that they came out in fairly quick succession--they're more usually spread out by at least a month between releases, meaning that there's about a 2-month window before updates become mandatory.

So while *we* probably won't include a setting to disable or control updates, *you* can still prevent them. The simplest option is to delete `AccessibilityInsights.Extensions.GitHubAutoUpdate.dll` from your installation, which will prevent the update code from running, and you'll be stuck on the same version forever. If you ever do update to a new version manually, you'll need to re-delete this file, as installing a new version will re-add it.

Comment: Where is that .dll file located?

Comment: In the Accessibility Insights installation folder, where the AccessibilityInsights.exe is also located (on my machine, `C:\Program Files (x86)\AccessibilityInsights\1.1`).